# Is it possible to cache images for docker-compose in CircleCI?

Tags: caching, docker-compose, circleci

I'm aware how to [cache dependencies](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/) in CircleCI:

```
- restore_cache:
    keys:
    - my-project-v1-{{ checksum "project.clj" }}
    # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
    - my-project-v1
- run: lein with-profile test deps
- save_cache:
    paths:
      - ~/.m2
    key: my-project-v1-{{ checksum "project.clj" }}
```

I'm also aware how to use `docker-compose`:

```
- run:
    name: Install Docker Compose
    command: |
      curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > ~/docker-compose
      chmod +x ~/docker-compose
      sudo mv ~/docker-compose /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
- run: docker-compose up -d
```

However, every time the job runs `docker-compose up -d`, it downloads the images, specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file. Is there a way to make CircleCI download them once and then use them (until `docker-compose.yml` is modified)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [docker layer caching](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/docker-layer-caching/) to achieve this by adding the following step as one of the first steps in your job:

```
     - setup_remote_docker: 
         docker_layer_caching: true
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think docker layer caching makes sense if I'm buidling a Docker image. However, I use docker-compose to bring up a bunch of dependencies (mysql, kafka) required for testing, so I don't think this is applicable for this case. Cheers.

Comment: The docs suggest that the feature is meant for building images, but all image layers will be cached, regardless of whether they are downloaded or built in that job.